# Rails - passing arbitrary parameters into search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4

I have passed a value into a search page via -

```
<%= link_to 'add', users_path(bookto: @book.id) %>
```

in the view and

```
@book = Book.find_by_id(params[:bookto])
```

in the receiving controller action.

I have a search form in my receiving (index) view

```
<%= form_tag users_path(params[bookto: @book.id]), method: 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= "#{@book.id}, #{@book.title}" %>

<% if @users %>
    <%= render partial: 'layouts/showusers', locals: {users: @users} %>
<% end %>
```

When I navigate through to the page

```
http://localhost:3000/users?bookto=1
```

The value of @book is passed properly. However, when I perform a search, the parameter is not being passed to

```
http://localhost:3000/users?utf8=✓&search=mysearch
```

I'm not passing the parameter through. I don't want to use this arbitrary parameter in the search, I just want it available to me to use once the search is complete. How do I achieve this? Do I need to add a search action to my controller?

Comment: If nothing else, you'd probably want to use `@book.id` as the parameter, not the book's string representation. How is the link rendering?

Comment: Hi - good point on @book.id, I've made that change and will update the question. When I run the search it falls over with 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#index Couldn't find Book without an ID' - thanks, Dan

Comment: This isn't really your problem but it's always safer to say `@book = Book.find_by_id(params[:bookto])` rather than `@book = Book.find(params[:bookto])`: the former will set @book to nil if it doesn't find a book, the latter will explode.

Comment: Thanks Max, that's good to know, have updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't just add a hidden field inside your search form like this

```
<%= form_tag users_path, method: 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :bookto, @book.id %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Because you would want to see bookid in your URL anyway, so this method is ok in your case.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do it - and am I right in thinking that the controller is picking up the value?

Comment: @RADan not sure what you mean. The params will be passed to controller and you can get the value through `params` object